# Bool logic (or) in gremlin match?

Tags: gremlin

In gremlin I have such query:

```
g.V().match(
  __.as('a').outE('x').as('a_x_b').inV().as('b'),
  __.as('a').outE('x1').as('a_x1_b').inV().as('b'),
  __.as('a').outE('x2').as('a_x2_b').inV().as('b'),
  __.as('b').outE('know').as('b_knows_c').inV().as('c'),
  __.as('b').outE('know1').as('b_knows1_c').inV().as('c')
).select('a','b','c', 'a_x_b', 'a_x1_b', 'b_knows1_c', 'a_x2_b')
```

But it is `and` logic. I want to using `or` in `g` such like

```
g.V().match(
  or(__.as('a').outE('x').as('a_x_b').inV().as('b'),
     __.as('a').outE('x1').as('a_x1_b').inV().as('b'),
     __.as('a').outE('x2').as('a_x2_b').inV().as('b')),
  or(__.as('b').outE('know').as('b_knows_c').inV().as('c'),
     __.as('b').outE('know1').as('b_knows1_c').inV().as('c'))
).select('a','b','c', 'a_x_b', 'a_x1_b', 'b_knows1_c', 'a_x2_b')
```

I think there is no such thing at gremlin. Why I need such thing. Because the one property of edge **don't support multi value** like the vertex. I want such multi value in one edge, So I must using multi label. Then I need to filter such label edge but using the `or` logic.

In another way: how to choose some edge label from multi label?

---

I figure out to such answer.

```
g.V().match(
  __.as('a').outE().as('a_x_b').filter(or(hasLabel('x'), hasLabel('x2'))).inV().as('b'),    
  __.as('b').outE().as('b_know_c').filter(or(hasLabel('know'), hasLabel('know1'))).inV().as('c')
).select('a','b','c', 'a_x_b', 'b_know_c')
```

still open the question for more methods.

turn label to property is ok too.

```
g.V().match(
  __.as('a').outE('x4').as('a_x_b').where(or(has('tag1', 1), has('tag2', 1))).inV().as('b'),
  __.as('b').outE().as('b_know_c').filter(or(hasLabel('know'), hasLabel('know1'))).inV().as('c')).select('a','b','c', 'a_x_b', 'b_know_c')
```

Comment: Which graph database are you using? When you say multi label, do you mean the edge has 3 labels or that there are multiple edges, each with a different label between A and B ?

Comment: I ask as I am not aware of any implementations that support multiple edge labels, but wanted to check in case you are using a DB that does support that.

Comment: just tinkerpop database.  At start I need one edge have `tag` property have valaue `tag1`,`tag2`. it don't support. Then I change to add two edge with two label `tag1`, `tag2`.   Then I want to query `tag1` or `tag2`

Comment: can we have multi label for one edge? I don't want have 3 different property name. For me if label was different I think it is a different edge.

Comment: I'm not aware of any implementation that allows multiple labels for one edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

1. In general I try to avoid the `match` step. It often leads to inefficient query execution. Pretty much everything you can do with a `match` can also be done using `where` steps.
2. You don't really need to use any `or` logic here. You can provide multiple labels to steps like `outE` and `hasLabel`. For example:

```java
gremlin> g.V(44).inE().label()
==>contains
==>contains
==>route
==>route
==>route
==>route
==>extra

gremlin> g.V(44).inE('extra','contains')
==>e[61286][8-extra->44]
==>e[57826][3743-contains->44]
==>e[54323][3729-contains->44]

gremlin> g.V(44).inE().hasLabel('extra','contains')
==>e[61286][8-extra->44]
==>e[57826][3743-contains->44]
==>e[54323][3729-contains->44]
```

Comment: simple replace match with where don't work in my example

Comment: in my example: it is `A-tag1-B` ,`A-tag2-B`, `A-tag3-B`.  I may want `tag1 and (tag2 or tag3)`.  At last I make `tag1` as label, `tag2` ,`tag3` as property.

Comment: There is a special form of `where` that uses a `where … as` type syntax, that allows you to write query expressions similar to yours, but avoiding `match`. You have to do a little query rewriting but it works well.